# " EXTRA_NVCCFLAGS=--cudart=shared" Command

Tags: linux, command-line

What exactly this command do:

```
make EXTRA_NVCCFLAGS=--cudart=shared
```

I used to implement rCUDA platform.is it used to compile the file?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

EXTRA_NVCCFLAGS=--cudart=shared tells the compiler (nvcc) to use the shared CUDA libraries. This is usually used to build the NVIDIA CUDA samples for RCUDA, so that they can take advantage of the remote GPUs using the rCUDAd server.